# ocaml null keyword: once but no more?

Tags: null, ocaml

At the ocaml toplevel (version 3.11.2), this simple expression is giving me an error:

```
# let a = [] in if null a then 0 else 1;;
Error: Unbound value null
```

I have just started learning ocaml from the [oreilly book](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/), which seems to use null as a keyword frequently - for example, top of page 32:

```
# let rec size a_list =
    if null a_list then 0
    else 1 + (size (List.tl a_list));;
```

I'm embarrassed to ask such an obviously googleable question here.  But after much googling I came up empty-handed.  So I'm as open to google query suggestions as I am to straightforward answers.  (failed google attempts: [ocaml "Error: Unbound value null"] [ocaml null keyword] [ocaml changelog null] [ocaml change null] ).

Question:  was null once an ocaml keyword, but no longer?  Or did I install ocaml wrong or misspell something?

I can of course replace every occurrence of "null" with "[ ]" in code, but I'm surprised that a verbatim copy of code from a book  gives me an error so early.  Is this book full of other gotchas?  I believe it was written with ocaml 2.04 in mind; is that too old?  I chose it because I liked the TOC and the free availability online.  Other than this null error (which I am still more ready to blame on myself than on the authors), the explanations are nice and I'm looking forward to the discussion of mixing functional & imperative style (mind-expanding for me, as someone only familiar with c/c++).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013654/differences-between-ocaml-2-and-3) addresses changes between version 2 and 3, and links to a changelog; neither of these mention the null thing.  In fact the oreilly book I linked in my Q is mentioned by the OP and recommended by someone answering the question.  I will probably comment on that thread after figuring out what's going on here.

Comment: I wasn't aware that `null` was ever a keyword.  Are you sure that isn't just a function that they've defined at some point?  AFAIK, there's no such notion of `null` in a true functional language.  Probably the closest thing would be the unit (`()`).

Comment: You are right!  Searched my pdf for "let null =" and sure enough, it's something defined in the book.  Thanks very much for clearing this up.  Now the meta-question is - should the question be left in place for people making the same silly mistake as me later?

Comment: @JeffMercado: `null` is a common name in FP for the function that tests whether a list is empty or not. It has nothing to do with null pointers/references.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

null is defined in the book on page 31.  It's a normal function that you can define yourself:

```
let null l = (l = [])
```

This nomenclature is more or less based on Lisp, where NIL is an empty list (also written as ()) and NULL is a predicate (a function returning true or false), exactly like null above.

Answer (score 4):

OCaml provides powerful [Pattern Matching](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora016.html), which allows you to define the function more readably:

```
let rec size a_list = match a_list with
 | [] -> 0
 | _ :: tl -> 1 + (size tl)
```

As pattern matching is often performed on the last argument, a special notation is available:

```
let rec size = function
 | [] -> 0
 | _ :: tl -> 1 + (size tl)
```

---

`null` could be defined shorter by using `(=)` (i.e., the test for equality as a normal/prefix function):

```
let null = (=) []
```